# Python matching some characters into a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract/match data from a string using regular expression but I don't seem to get it.

I wan't to extract from the following string the i386 (The text between the last - and .iso):

```
/xubuntu/daily/current/lucid-alternate-i386.iso
```

This should also work in case of:

```
/xubuntu/daily/current/lucid-alternate-amd64.iso
```

And the result should be either i386 or amd64 given the case.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will be matching several of these lines using re.compile() and saving the resulting regular expression object for reuse [is more efficient](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.compile).

```
s1 = "/xubuntu/daily/current/lucid-alternate-i386.iso"
s2 = "/xubuntu/daily/current/lucid-alternate-amd64.iso"

pattern = re.compile(r'^.+-(.+)\..+$')

m = pattern.match(s1)
m.group(1)
'i386'

m = pattern.match(s2)
m.group(1)
'amd64'
```

Comment: you don't need regexs for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925306/python-matching-some-characters-into-a-string/2925399#2925399

Comment: I know but it is tagged python and regex

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) in this case (instead of regex):

```
>>> str = "/xubuntu/daily/current/lucid-alternate-i386.iso"
>>> str.split(".iso")[0].split("-")[-1]
'i386'
```

`split` gives you a list of elements on which your string got 'split'. Then using Python's [slicing syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation/509295#509295) you can get to the appropriate parts.

Comment: `str.rsplit('.iso', 1)[0].rsplit('-', 1)[-1]`

Comment: `str.rpartition('.iso')[0].rpartition('-')[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
r"/([^-]*)\.iso/"
```

The bit you want will be in the first capture group.

Comment: Were you trying to use `match()` or `search()`? Since this is a partial-match pattern, it should be used with `search()` not `match()` (since `match()` attempts to match the entire string, not just a portion).

Answer (score 1):

First off, let's make our life simpler and only get the file name.

```
>>> os.path.split("/xubuntu/daily/current/lucid-alternate-i386.iso")
('/xubuntu/daily/current', 'lucid-alternate-i386.iso')
```

Now it's just a matter of catching all the letters between the last dash and the '.iso'.

Comment: I still face the problem that can't get to extract the desired text :( (I've never been good with regexp)

Answer (score 0):

The expression should be without the leading trailing slashes.

```
import re

line = '/xubuntu/daily/current/lucid-alternate-i386.iso'
rex = re.compile(r"([^-]*)\.iso")
m = rex.search(line)
print m.group(1)
```

Yields 'i386'

Answer (score 0):

```
reobj = re.compile(r"(\w+)\.iso$")
match = reobj.search(subject)
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
else:
    result = ""
```

Subject contains the filename and path.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import os
>>> path = "/xubuntu/daily/current/lucid-alternate-i386.iso"
>>> file, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(path)[1])
>>> processor = file[file.rfind("-") + 1:]
>>> processor
'i386'
```